# Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'LastName' in table 'HumanCustomers' is specified more than once

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, migration, entity-framework-core

After update my model and add data annotation.

Then I executed add-migration and update-database commands and I got the following error:

> Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'LastName' in
>   table 'HumanCustomers' is specified more than once.

But LastName field once used.

HumanCustomer Class:

```
public class HumanCustomer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MinLength(2)]
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string Name
        {
            get => Name;
            set
            {
                value.TrimAndReduce();
            }
        }
        [Required]
        [MinLength(2)]
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string LastName
        {
            get => LastName;
            set
            {
                value = value.TrimAndReduce();
            }
        }
        [NotMapped]
        public string FullName
        {
            get { return Name + LastName; }

        }
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
        public int GenderId { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
        public int IdentityTypeId { get; set; }
        public string IdentityCode { get; set; }   
        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual User User { get; set; }  
        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("IdentityTypeId")]
        public virtual IdentityType IdentityType { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("GenderId")]
        public virtual Gender Gender { get; set; }
    }
```

and migration:

```
 protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
                name: "LastName",
                table: "HumanCustomers",
                maxLength: 20,
                nullable: false,
                defaultValue: "");

            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<string>(
                name: "Name",
                table: "HumanCustomers",
                maxLength: 20,
                nullable: false,
                defaultValue: "");
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
                name: "LastName",
                table: "HumanCustomers");

            migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
                name: "Name",
                table: "HumanCustomers");
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting and recreating the migration?

Comment: No, only  I want to update the table in sql @rad

Comment: check your table in database to see if you have already column with name LastName there or not. It seems that you have already a column with this name there!

Comment: Yes there @VahidFarahmandian

Comment: @Ahmad so you can not run your migration as database will terminate it with the aforementioned error. Simply drop that column from database, or comment the code where tries to add the column in your migration.(This is based on your situation)

Answer (score 0):

The error is clearly indicating that you already have a column called `LastName` in your table and the migration cannot be applied to add a new column with the same name.
Either go to the database management system and remove the column manually, or if you have just switched to code-first and you have existing schema that you want to ignore in the next migration then delete the migration file and create a new one using `-IgnoreChanges` flag:

```
Add-Migration migrationName –IgnoreChanges
```

Though, as @Ahmad commented, `-IgnoreChanges` is not supported in EF Core, therefore, one thing you can do is that if you don't want to bother deleting the column from the table manually, you can comment out the `Add LastName` code in the `Up` method.

Comment: It does not work in Entity Framework core. Error: `A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'IgnoreChanges'.`

Comment: @Ahmad Yes, thank you for reminding, I updated the answer.